# Get nested element to respect max-height restriction of parent elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently try to implement a container with a header, content and footer section.
It uses the following HTML

```
<div class="component">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="scroll-content">
      Scrollable content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body  {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.component {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scroll-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: lavender;
  max-height: calc(100% - 75px - 50px);
  // this one changes dynamically but should respect max-height
  height: 800px;
}
```

Want i want is that the content container can grow/shrink dynamically w.r.t. to the scroll-content container content size, and gets a scrollbar when growing larger than the max-height. Unfortunately, i can not get this to work.

Here is a link to a codepen containing the same code: https://codepen.io/drivt/pen/zYjXjoK

Does anyone have an idea what i need to do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Everything is fine, just put something there (.scroll-content) that is larger than max-height.

Answer (score -1):

In your css, change `overflow-y:auto` to `overflow-y:scroll`

```
.scroll-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Full Code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.component {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.footer {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.scroll-content {
  height: calc(100% - 75px - 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="scroll-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not help to solve the problem. The scroll-container is still overflowing. Besides that i only want the scrollbar to appear on actual overflow.

Comment: What is the scroll-container? I don't see it in your code?

Comment: The one with the class `scroll-content` on it (i.e. the container for which you suggested to set `overflow-y: scroll`)